# How to get IsMotion status from IP-Cam using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, soap, onvif

I'm working on a VBA tool to switch IP-cam streams to several VLC-players. My cams are all Onvif compatible with build-in motion detection which generates a boolean. If a cam has "IsMotion: = true" the stream should open.

How can I get this var into VBA?

I was trying to generate a SOAP request to each IP (192.168.120.111 - 119) but all i got is some html code without any useful information...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
...
</script>
</html>
```

Is there an easy way to get it? like...

```
bIsMotion(1) = http://user:password@192.168.120.111/onvif/device_service/IsMotion.value
```

Sorry for my bad english!